# How to build huawei app store application?

Tags: android, flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

We have build our mobile application android and ios using flutter. Now is it possible to build Huawei application using that same codebase ? if not then what we have to learn to create Huawei application?

We are searching Huawei documentations but did not found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same code as the Android application the one that you need to upload to AppGallery. Just need to create a Huawei account and use the keys agServices provided there

Answer (score 0):

You should also note that if you use play services in your app, then you will either need to disable these features if the device does not support play, or use the equivalent hms libraries.

```
fun isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
    val resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)
    return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS
}
```

and for huawei

```
fun isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val huaweiApiAvailability = HuaweiApiAvailability.getInstance()
    val resultCode = huaweiApiAvailability.isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(context)
    return resultCode == com.huawei.hms.api.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS
}
```

is basic android kotlin code to determine which of the libraries are available. (once you have the dependencies installed)

There's more information about flutter specifically on the Huawei developers site [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started-flutter-0000001057642285).

Comment: We are using google maps in it, will it work or not ?

Comment: That'll depend on the device. Some Huawei devices don't have play services. And if that's the case, google maps won't work on those devices, so you should try to swap out that feature for the huawei alternative.